# Kendo chart remove attribute using javascript

Tags: javascript, charts, kendo-ui

I have a kendo column chart, the datasource gets refreshed when different criterias are set via date pickers.

I want to stop the chart from displaying the value axis as a decimal and the only way I have found so far is to either set the format, which results in duplicating numbers, or the major unit, which if my data changes, then this results in overlapping value axis labels. Neither are suitable.

The only way I can now think to do it is to dynamically set the major unit based on whether my maximum value is less than 10, if it is then the major unit is set to 1, if not no major unit isn't set.

This should work fine but, if the major unit gets set to 1, and the data changes I now need to find a way to clear the major unit if my new maximum value is greater than 10.

In javascript I have:

```
if (highest <= 10) {
   chart.data("kendoChart").options.valueAxis.majorUnit = 1;
} else {
   chart.data("kendoChart").options.valueAxis.majorUnit.remove(); // This does not work
}
```

I can't just set majorUnit to null or 0, it doesn't like that and there is no documentation on the correct syntax for removing this kind of attribute.

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me:

```
chart.data("kendoChart").options.valueAxis.majorUnit = undefined;
```

Don't forget to call

```
chart.data("kendoChart").refresh();
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an example to show?
Does it help you if you just hide the value axis lines?

http://docs.kendoui.com/api/dataviz/chart#configuration-categoryAxis.line.visible

```
chart.data('kendoChart').options.valueAxis.line.visible = false;
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't just hide the scale, Istill want to be able to see it, I just want to remove the MajorUnit property. I thought you might be able to do it like you remove attributes on html elements, but if that is possible I don't know the syntax.

Comment: if you can, make a jsFiddle example so we can see the actual problem in detail.

Comment: This is what I have ended up doing as there is no obvious way to remove the major unit. I have created two value axis's and then where I check the highest value, I am either hidding or showing the correct value axis. Seems ridiculous that you can't just remove the major unit but nevermind.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using datasource, you can put this code into requestEnd function, so no chart refresh is required:

```
$("#chart").kendoChart({
    dataSource: {
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: url,
                dataType: "json",
                type: 'POST'
            }
        },
        // This is to set a step that looks appropriate for the size of the graph
        requestEnd: function(e){
            var max = 1;

            // Iterate over your own data as you need, here my data returns "Category" and "Count" in each row.
            e.response.forEach(function(row){
                if(row.Count > max)
                    max = row.Count;
            });

            if(max <= 10)
                $("#chart").data('kendoChart').options.valueAxis.majorUnit = 2;
            else
                $("#chart").data('kendoChart').options.valueAxis.majorUnit = undefined;
        },
    },
```